# Jsoup not working properly on specified website

Tags: jsoup

This is a chinese website.([Link](http://pchome.megatime.com.tw/stock/sid1101.html))

I want to use Jsoup to parse this website, but it seems Jsoup not working.

A very simple code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pchome.megatime.com.tw/stock/sid1101.html")
            .timeout(0).get();
Elements links = doc.select("a");

for(Element e : links) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

And nothing coming out.

My Jsoup can parse every website except this one. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.

Comment: I want to ask a question: What is the purpose of specifying an user agent? Is user agent necessary to add no matter what URLs?                     Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site is doing a funny thing, first it returns a redirection (http code 302) and then returns a mini page that does a form submit with a `is_check=1` parameter. We have to follow all these steps.

Also, you need to specify an user agent.

Summarizing, just do:

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://pchome.megatime.com.tw/stock/sid1101.html")
        .followRedirects(false)
        .timeout(0)
        .method(Method.GET)
        .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
        .execute();

String location = res.header("Location");

res = Jsoup.connect("http://pchome.megatime.com.tw/stock/sid1101.html")
        .timeout(0)
        .data("is_check", "1")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
        .header("Referer", location)
        .execute();

Document doc = res.parse();
Elements links = doc.select("a");

for(Element e : links) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

And you'll get plenty of links.